# A generalisation of closed and bounded subsets of non-Archimedean fields to topological spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, oa.operator-algebras, banach-algebras, non-archimedean-fields

The definition of compactness in topological spaces generalises the notion of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ being closed and bounded, as expressed by the Heine-Borel Theorem.

In finite-dimensional vector spaces over non-Archimedean fields (the main example I am interested in is the field $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ of complex [*Hahn series*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_series)), the Heine-Borel Theorem clearly fails. For example, the closed unit ball in $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is non-compact since it contains the sequence of positive integers, which has no convergent subsequence.

Yet as with any metric space, a compact subset is closed and bounded. It follows that compactness is a strictly stronger condition in $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ than being closed and bounded, too strong to include closed balls. This made me wonder if there is an analogous concept in topological spaces (or at least in Hausdorff spaces), akin to compactness but weaker, which is equivalent to being closed and bounded for subsets of $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$.

In the literature on non-Archimedean functional analysis, there are some weaker forms of compactness mentioned, such as '$c$-compactness', which is defined in terms of convex filterbases (see [this book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Functional-Analysis-Valuation-Mathematics-1971-06-01/dp/B01K2P5MRI)) and also 'compactoidity' (see [this book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Locally-Non-Archimedean-Cambridge-Advanced-Mathematics/dp/0521192439)), but this assumes a vector space structure.

The ultimate motivation for looking into this is to see if certain fundamental results in the spectral theory of Banach algebras (such as $\sigma(a)$ always being non-empty) work over $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$. As a disclaimer, I should add that I am probably a bit naive and realise that this may not work. Any advice would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: There is no topological characterization of closed and bounded subsets of this space. This is because it contains subsets which are homeomorphic and of which one is closed and bounded and the other isn't.

Comment: Not quite what you are asking but maybe useful nonetheless. The generalization of "compact iff closed and bounded" to arbitrary metric spaces is "compact iff complete and totally bounded"

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Yes, that's true, although unfortunately closed balls in this non-Archimedean setting are not even totally bounded.

Comment: @Wojowu Do you have an example of such a homeomorphism?

Comment: Let $A=\mathbb N$ and $B=\{t^{-n}\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$. They are both discrete, so any bijection between them is a homeomorphism.